# canvas gauge dynamic object update value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas, gauge

I am using Canvas-gauge from here [canvas-gauges.com](https://canvas-gauges.com)

I create multiple gauges dynamically in a loop as follows (loop not shown);

```
<canvas id="canvas_<?php echo $device_pk; ?>"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var gg = "gauge_" + "<?php echo $device_pk; ?>";
    this[gg] = new RadialGauge({
        renderTo: 'canvas_<?php echo $device_pk; ?>',
        height: 200,
        .....other properties here.....
    }).draw();
</script>
```

which displays the gauges correctly.

I then want to update the gauge values using javascript/ajax. In ajax, I post each/all the $device_pk values and the result returned is a json string formatted as `{"gauge_8":"22.3","gauge_12":"0","gauge_15":"-5"}` which I then do

```
success : function(result) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(data, function (k,v) {
         console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
         //k.value = v;
         //k.value = Number(v);
         k['value']= Number(v);
     });
 },
```

which shows me the correct 'k' and 'v'info in the console log.
What I can't work out is how to update the gauge named 'k' with the data value 'v'.
This is normally done using `gauge_23.value = 10.2;` on the condition that the created gauge is called 'gauge_23' of course.

Just to test, I identified a correct gauge name for a gauge being displayed and temporarily hard coded in `gauge_23.value = 10.2;` to occur from a button click and it works and updates the gauge.

I am certain the problem lay in the way I am trying to update the dynamically created gauge objects (are they objects?) or the way I am creating them, but I have just about given up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without all your code its a bit hard to know the answer so I will guess the answer.

Your setup code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gg = "gauge_" + "<?php echo $device_pk; ?>";
    this[gg] = new RadialGauge({
        renderTo: 'canvas_<?php echo $device_pk; ?>',
        height: 200,
        .....other properties here.....
    }).draw();
</script>
```

You are assigning the property `gauge_23` of the object `this` a reference to a gauge object. Read as is this would refer to the global scope which is window

Thus the you are doing this

```
    window["gauge_" + "<?php echo $device_pk; ?>"] = new RadialGauge({
        renderTo: 'canvas_<?php echo $device_pk; ?>',
        height: 200,
        .....other properties here.....
    }).draw();
```

If window is not the correct scope then use whatever object `this` is at the bottom of answer

Then when you set the gauge from the downloaded data you do

```
success : function(result) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(data, function (k,v) {
         console.log(k + ' is ' + v);
         k['value']= Number(v);
     });
 },
```

You say the console log outputs "gauge_23 is 10" if the parsed json object is `{guage_23 : "10"}` that would mean `k` is a string. You are adding the property `value` to the string `k` ad assigning `10` to it.

Assuming that your setup code was running in the glbal scope an that the gauges are properties of window you can change the code to

```
    $.each(data, function (k,v) {
         window[k].value = Number(v); // window or whatever the this was
     });
```

I would assume you need to update the gauge after setting value but I leave that up to you.

Comment: Hi @Blindman67, thank you for your 'guess', that works perfectly. The actual command to update the gauge is `gauge_name.value = number`. Excellent!